# Cant get Castor's MappingTool to work

Tags: java, web-services, web, castor

I’m trying to auto generate a mapping file using this program using Castor 1.3.2.

But here is the exception I get -
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class org.exolab.castor.mapping.xml.types.BindXmlNodeType.element

This is a fairly basic test, what am I doing wrong?

public class CastorMapping {

```
    public CastorMapping()
    {
        try
        {
            MappingTool tool = new MappingTool();
            tool.setInternalContext(new org.castor.xml.BackwardCompatibilityContext());
            tool.addClass(TestRequest.class);
            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("gen_mapping.xml" );
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(file);
            tool.write(writer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new CastorMapping();
    }
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this myself and I believe you are doing everything correctly.

I browsed the castor source code and as far as I can tell, they broke the MappingTool somewhere between 1.3 and 1.3.2 when they redesigned BindXmlNodeType to be an enum class instead of a regular class.  There is some code where they are looking for an BindXmlNodeType.element, but now that BindXmlNodeType is an enum they need to look up ELEMENT (caps).  But I digress...

If you can afford to revert to castor 1.3, everything should work.

BTW - I tried to upgrade to 1.3.3-rc1 but Intellij could not resolve the maven dependencies.  For example castor-xml in 1.3.3-rc1 now depends on Spring! It's possible that this bug is fixed in a later version, but I am not hopeful.

Comment: @Guido Simone, Does **Castor-0.9.5.4** version support this? I could not find `BackwardCompatibilityContext` class in there.

Comment: Thank you, your answer explained our huge problem!